# How to prevent the block from being displayed, finally, if there is no path to the file

Tags: java

Problem: if the path to the file was not specified in the arguments, then it still displays the phrase "The file was closed". This works 2 times. In uploadToFile and read method. I pass one path in the arguments, and the second is written in the DownloadFile

```
    public class Task implements AutoCloseable {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String DownloadFile = "C:\\Users\\VGilenko\\IdeaProjects\\Task\\src\\main\\resources\\Out.txt";
    Map<String, Departament> departments = new HashMap<>();
    String path = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : null;

    read(path, departments);
    transferToDepartment(departments, DownloadFile);
}
    
        private static void uploadToFile(List download, String path) {
            int i = 0;
            try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path, false)) {
                ...
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            } finally {
                System.out.println("The file was closed");
            }
        }

public static void transferToDepartment(Map<String, Departament> departments, String downloadFile) {
        List<String> download = new ArrayList<>();
        ...
        }
        uploadToFile(download, downloadFile);
    }

    
        public static void read(String path, Map<String, Departament> departments) throws IOException {
            assert path != null;
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "CP1251")); br) {
                .....
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("The file was not found, check the path");
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("Correct the file path, step out of the array");
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println("You forgot to register the path to the file");
            } finally {
                System.out.println("The file was closed");
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void close() {
            System.out.println("The file was closed");
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling `uploadToFile`?

Comment: Updated the code, showed where I'm calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your printout "The file was closed" in your `finally` statement. If you don't specify a file, you will catch an Exception, and your `finally` block will be executed.

An easy fix would be to check for the existence of the path (not being empty, not being `null`).

Comment: Yes, of course I know that. But the bottom line is that the message is displayed with the content that the file being read has been closed. But we didn't read anything, because there was no path to the file. And in the program I use try with resources, and therefore I want everything to be processed correctly. I check it like this: `String path = args.length> 0? args [0]: null;`

Comment: @Blacit well, that's how `finally` [works](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) "The `finally` block *always* executes when the `try` block exits."

Comment: But isn't the parameter `null`, if no argument is given? This might result in an IOException in the FileWriter-Constructor, which in turn will lead you directly to your `finally` block.

Comment: Okay, look. The user decided to play with our program, takes and does not enter anything into the arguments. In this case, an exception should be executed, everything works like that, writes that the path to the file is not specified. But at the same time, finally blocks are triggered, which indicate that the file being read is closed. I thought that if we use `try with resources`, then we should definitely use a finally block. 
In my case, I did that I removed the finally block and moved the notification that I closed the file directly into the code.

Comment: Can you then tell me how to make the program stop going further if the path to the file was not specified? Use System.exit (0); - I will not, because it is not entirely correct and prohibited.

Comment: You could check the path in advance, f.e. like that:
```if (path != null && new File(path).exists()) {  
  //do your stuff  
} else {     //file does not exist  
  System.err.println("No path was given, or no file present at the given location");  
  System.exit(-1);   //negative exit codes usually represent errors  
}```